# Show/hide div according to select option in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Searched the internet. Learnt how to do this. Implemented it. But it doesn't work. 
I want to show the div student when student is selected and the div teacher when teacher is selected. This is a part of a jsp file.

**HTML code :**

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
         <select id="userType">
             <option value="student">STUDENT</option>
             <option value="teacher">TEACHER</option>
             <option value="admin">ADMIN</option>
         </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
<table>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var elem = document.getElementById('userType');
    elem.onchange = function() {
        var studentDiv = document.getElementById('student');
        var teacherDiv = document.getElementById('teacher');
        studentDiv.style.display = (this.value.equals("student")) ? 'block':'none';
        teacherDiv.style.display = (this.value.equals("teacher")) ? 'block':'none';
    };

</script>
```

I've been trying to get this right since morning. Tried other methods as well. Nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q9Lx2ffn/

Comment: Your solution has some problems and is throwing errors in the console. Debug these out in your browser developer tools. That's how to learn how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Change `equals` to `==` in your code and it works [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/719/)

```js
var elem = document.getElementById('userType');
elem.onchange = function() {
  var studentDiv = document.getElementById('student');
  var teacherDiv = document.getElementById('teacher');
  studentDiv.style.display = (this.value == "student") ? 'block' : 'none';
  teacherDiv.style.display = (this.value == "teacher") ? 'block' : 'none';
};
```

Comment: Why use jsfiddle when you could just include a snippet in the answer 9_9

Comment: I have tried this too. And yes, it works in jfiddle. And it should work everywhere. But for some very weird reason, this doesn't work on my computer. I have no clue why. I tried opening the file with both Firefox and Chrome. If style display is set to none, nothing shows even after changing the selection. If I delete the style attribute, both teacher and student is shown, even on selecting different options. This makes no sense. The code should work. This never happens.

Comment: If your js code is in separate file make sure you included it correctly, also try with this `HTML` code https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/721/

Answer (score 0):

You may get value of selected option like below:

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/moonlife/4ovc2cg5/)**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var elem = document.getElementById('userType');
    elem.onchange = function() {
        var studentDiv = document.getElementById('student');
        var teacherDiv = document.getElementById('teacher');
        studentDiv.style.display = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == "student" ? 'block':'none';
        teacherDiv.style.display = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value == "teacher" ? 'block':'none';
    };

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 studentDiv.style.display = (this.value==="student") ? 'block':'none';
 teacherDiv.style.display = (this.value==="teacher") ? 'block':'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

Two problems immediately pop out:

You are trying to select items that do not have id's defined.
You are calling a non-existent ".value" on the element value property.

These errors will be reported in your browser developer tools. Use them.